# Jest: mock one of several exported components

Tags: reactjs, mocking, jestjs

In component I want to test I import several components from a parent component:

```
import {
  ResponsiveContainer,
  LineChart,
  Line,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Legend,
} from 'recharts';
```

How do I mock just `ResponsiveContainer` leaving other components untouched?

Update: Dennie de Lange prompted to use dependency injection in this case. Completely agree. But I faced the following problem. Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  ResponsiveContainer,
  LineChart,
} from 'recharts';
import moment from 'moment';

class CustomLineChart extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { data, container: Container = ResponsiveContainer } = this.props;
    if (!data) return null;
    return (
      <div className="lineChart">
        <Container>
          <LineChart data={data}>
            ... lots of other stuff here
          </LineChart>
        </Container>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomLineChart;
```

and here's my test:

```
const Mock = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

describe('<LineChart />', () => {    
  it('renders data if provided', () => {
    const component = create(<LineChart data={data} container={Mock} />);
    const tree = component.toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

And here's what snapshot I get for this:

```
<div
  className="lineChart"
>
  <div />
</div>
```

So children of `Container` are missing for some reason. Any ideas?

Update 2: Actually the above implementation is correct, this was `LineChart` rendering nothing in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By making it configurable in the component you want to test?

```
const MyTestComponent = ({container:Container=ResponsiveContainer}) => ...
```

This allows you to create a mock and supply it to the `MyTestComponent`

Comment: I was so interested in finding a way to mock it with jest, that forgot about dependency injection :) Thanks for reminding. But I still can't get it done. I've tried your solution and provided `const Mock = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;` to `container` prop, but I get just `<div />` as the snapshot. Any ideas?

Comment: It probably depends on the Component, can't really say without seeing more implementation

Comment: I've added implementation details.

Comment: Have you tried to append a simple child and see the result? It looks like LineChart isn't rendering.. So try,  <Container>
          <div>test</div>
        </Container>